# Setting up a truly non-required subparser with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like my program to allow any string to be passed as an argument, but also to allow subcommands. For example, these would all be valid:

```
$ python argtest.py 'hello world'
$ python argtest.py version
$ python argtest.py help
```

I do not want users to have to use `--`, e.g., `python argparse.py -- 'hello world'`.

If I set up a subcommand parser to handle 'version' and 'help', it will then complain that 'hello world' isn't a valid subcommand.

My code:

```
parser = argparse_flags.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(required=False)
subparsers.add_parser('version')
subparsers.add_parser('help')
ns, remainder = parser.parse_known_args(argv[1:])
```

Yields:

```
$ python argtest.py 'hello world'
usage: argtest.py [-h] {version,help} ...
argtest.py: error: invalid choice: 'hello world' (choose from 'version', 'help')
```

The only fix I've come up with is to create a "fallback" subcommand and then manually add it with `parser.parse_known_args(['fallback'] + argv[1:])` by either:

- Looking for this first argument not prefixed with '-' and then see if it's in `subparsers.choices`.
- Catch the SystemExit raised by argparse when no subparsers match (and temporarily redirecting stderr so it doesn't spam the CLI).

All of this is kind of gross, is there a better way to get the behavior I want? I just want argparse to be a little more chill about not finding a subcommand.

Comment: As I've explained in other SO, `subparsers` is a positional argument with `choices`, and strings are allocated by position, not value.  So what you want is not possible with `argparse` as created.

Comment: The intention of subparsers is allow a variety of flagged arguments, including default '-h/--help', followed by delegation to the specified subparser and its arguments.  The fact that it may be not-required is actually an accident, the side effect of another patch.

Comment: Subparsers only help if `help` and `version` take different sets of additional arguments.  If you just want a string, make it a plain positional, and do your command branching after parsing.  A positional with 'choices'  would have the same 'bad choice' problem.  Do your own testing, in `type`or after.

Comment: FWIW this is a pared-down example for simplicity: I do want subcommands to take their own arguments.

Comment: What is `argparse_flags`? A typo?

Comment: `argparse_flags` is from the absl-py flag parsing library. It's a pretty thin wrapper around argparse. I meant to simplify the question down to just use argparse but missed that one, sorry for the confusion. (ref: https://pypi.org/project/absl-py/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_subparsers` is a variant on `add_argument`, creating a `Action` subclass with `nargs=argparse.PARSER`.

Only `optionals` get their `flag` string selected by value.  Positionals are allocated strictly by postion and `nargs`.  This is done in `_get_values`.  For a parser

```
 # PARSER arguments convert all values, but check only the first
        elif action.nargs == PARSER:
            value = [self._get_value(action, v) for v in arg_strings]
            self._check_value(action, value[0])
```

So all remaining strings in `arg_strings` are allocated.  `_get_value` tests against `type`, which here is just a pass through `str`.  `_check_value` tests the first of that list against `choices`.

For subparsers, the `choices` are the subparser names and their aliases.  So this is where your 'hello_world' fails.

As you note, exit errors can be caught. Recently a  `exit_on_error` parameter has been added that will raise the error instead of exiting.  It doesn't work in all cases, but I think it should work here.  And as documented you can also tweak the `error` and `exit` methods to change how errors are raised.

Normally a `positional` is not-required only if `nargs` is '?' or '*'.  And a due to tweak of old patching, also this 'PARSER' case.  There's no mechanism to retry allocating a string if it fails the `type` or `choices`.

If there are multiple `positionals`, strings are allocated in a `re` greedy sense.  First argument gets as many values as it wants, etc.  So be careful when stringing '+*?' `nargs` together.

In sum, I think the subparsers mechanism works best if you define a bunch of `optionals` for the main parsers, and then the `add_subparsers` Action.  That way it can handle the `optionals`, if any, and then branch to the chosen subparser to handle the rest.  A `positional` can be defined for the main parser, but avoid open ended `nargs`.

Another thing with subparsers.  Use different argument `dest` in the main and subparsers.  That way the subparser defaults won't step on main parser defaults.